# SQL Server - Getting the opposite of a where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a data set where I would like to filter out rows that meet a specific condition, however it's proving a lot more trickier than I thought it would do.

Essentially I want to do something along the lines of `WHERE (column1 NOT LIKE 'Z%' and column2 != '2')` with the view that the query will only return rows in which a specific row **doesn't** have the value like 'Z%' in column1 and **doesn't** have the value '2' in column2.

For example:

**Full data set**

```
column1 | column2
-----------------
ACAL    | 2
-----------------
ZVBBU3  | 2
-----------------
FSKE2   | X
```

**Data set that I want**

```
column1 | column2
-----------------
ACAL    | 2
-----------------
FSKE2   | X
```

However, it doesn't do that. So I thought there may be a programming approach like `WHERE (!(column1 LIKE 'Z% and column2 = '2'))` where `!` will return the opposite of the criteria specified, but this throws a syntax error. Is there any way of doing what I want to achieve?

Comment: Can there be any NULL's? If yes, what do you want in that case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
WHERE NOT (column1 LIKE 'Z%' AND column2 = '2')
```

You were on the right track with the negation, but should use `NOT` to negate instead of `!`.

Note that

```
WHERE (COLUMN1 NOT LIKE 'Z%') OR (COLUMN2 != '2')
```

should work as well as [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) for logic states that

> The negation of a conjunction is the disjunction of the negations. 
> The
>   negation of a disjunction is the conjunction of the negations.

Comment: Ah, the good old `NOT` operator. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction as well as the useful reference to the mentioned laws.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably what you are trying to write:

```
WHERE NOT(column1 LIKE 'Z%' AND column2 = '2')
```

With T-SQL in SQL Server, although it works, you should use:

- **NOT** => !
- **<>** => !=
- **=** => ==